# VBA runtime error -2147188720 Object does not exist

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to run a VBA code through excel which creates multiple powerpoint files using a loop. However, I get a runtime error everytime the loop increments. The error appears when `myshape.LockAspectRatio = False` executes for any iteration after the first.

I also get

> runtime error -2147188160 - 'Shapes(unknown member) : Invalid request

when `ppslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` executes. This occurs at random times during execution.

Here's what I'm trying to do: exec_sorted is a dictionary of a collection

```
For Each iter1 In accExec_sorted.Keys()

    Set ppapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set pppress = ppapp.Presentations.Add
    pppress.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeLetterPaper
    Set ppslide = pppress.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
    ppslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = iter1

    i = 2
    Set lenderID = accExec_sorted(iter1)

    For Each iter In lenderID
        ind_len.Range("l_id1") = iter
        Set ppslide = pppress.Slides.Add(i, ppLayoutBlank)


        ind_len.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ppslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Set myshape = ppslide.Shapes(1)
        myshape.LockAspectRatio = False

        myshape.Left = 420
        myshape.Top = 40
        myshape.Width = 290
        myshape.Height = 160

        ind_len.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ppslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Set myshape = ppslide.Shapes(2)
        myshape.LockAspectRatio = False

        myshape.Left = 420
        myshape.Top = 205
        myshape.Width = 290
        myshape.Height = 160


        i = i + 1

    Next iter

    pppress.SaveAs intro.Range("dest_path") & intro.Range("investor") & "_" & intro.Range("period") & "_" & iter1 & ".pptx"
    pppress.Close
    ppapp.Quit
    Set ppapp = Nothing

Next iter1
```

Comment: What line does it crash on? Have you tried placing `Option Explicit` as the very first line in your code? Also, you need to set all variables that have used the `Set` statement to `Nothing` before the end of your `Next iter1` loop.

Comment: The error appears when myshape.LockAspectRatio = False executes for any iteration after the first.

Comment: I set all the variables to nothing and it seems to work. why would that be causing this issue?

Comment: When you set an object in memory and do not clear it out you get a memory conflict.  The scenario is the same as trying to fit two cars in a single parking space, you have to either move one car or destroy it otherwise, the two cars will crash.

Comment: Thanks for the help on that @IAmNerd2000! I also get a runtime error -2147188160 saying which says 'Shapes(unknown member) : Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable. I did not get this yesterday. I get it on the following line: `ppslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`

Comment: It is hard to say exactly what is happening as we can't test your code. are you wanting to simply paste the chart in as a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK Shreyans,  I had to modify the code to work on my end and play around with some things, but it works. I then, inserted your code into what I have.  The problem was that you were trying to paste a chartobject as an object into the presentation instead of copying the object as a picture. Once I did that and set the objects to nothing it worked. Here is my code.

NOTE: You can modify it back to using the Powerpoint.Application variable without using the create object. I just did this to make it easier on me.

```
Sub CopyPastePicture()

    For Each iter1 In accExec_sorted.Keys()

        Set ppapp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        Set pppress = ppapp.Presentations.Add
        pppress.PageSetup.SlideSize = 2
        Set ppslide = pppress.Slides.Add(1, 1)
        ppslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = iter1

        i = 2
        Set lenderID = accExec_sorted(iter1)

        For Each iter In lenderID
            ind_len.Range("l_id1") = iter

            Set ppslide = pppress.Slides.Add(i, 12)

            ind_len.ChartObjects("Chart 6").CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
            ppslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 2
            Set myshape = ppslide.Shapes(ppslide.Shapes.Count)

            myshape.LockAspectRatio = False

            myshape.Left = 420
            myshape.Top = 40
            myshape.Width = 290
            myshape.Height = 160

            Set myshape = Nothing

            ind_len.ChartObjects("Chart 7").CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
            ppslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 2
            Set myshape = ppslide.Shapes(ppslide.Shapes.Count)

            myshape.LockAspectRatio = False

            myshape.Left = 420
            myshape.Top = 205
            myshape.Width = 290
            myshape.Height = 160

            Set myshape = Nothing
            Set ppslide = Nothing

            i = i + 1

        Next iter

        pppress.SaveAs intro.Range("dest_path") & intro.Range("investor") & "_" & intro.Range("period") & "_" & iter1 & ".pptx"
        pppress.Close
        ppapp.Quit
        Set ppapp = Nothing
        Set pppress = Nothing
        Set ppslide = Nothing
        Set myshape = Nothing

    Next iter1

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI you do not need to use triple back ticks if you have already indented the code with four spaces. Doing so will add an unnecessary/extra level of indentation to your code, requiring users to scroll more than necessary.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH I thought both were needed.

Comment: It works when I set shapes to nothing and copy picture. Thanks! @IAmNerd2000